# How do I re-organise a python module to not reflect the directory structure?

Tags: python, module

I'm writing a code generator and want to be able to export to different file types. The `foo` module holds the snippets for different classes (subA, subA, subC). `bar.py` and `baz.py` hold the snippets for different languages.
I find it much more convenient to import `foo.bar` and get all the snippets for the `bar` language than having to import `bar` for every class.
Similarly I'd rather have all snippets for a particular class in the same directory, hence the following organisation

```
foo
| __init__.py
+ subA
| | __init__.py
| | bar.py
| ` baz.py
+ subB
| | __init__.py
| | bar.py
| ` baz.py
` subC
  | __init__.py
  | bar.py
  ` baz.py
```

that I want to be able to import like this:
`from foo.bar import subA` should give me access to `foo/subA/bar.py`

I think I need to do this re-organisation in `foo/__init__.py` but I can't figure out what exactly to do. My guess is that I need to create an empty module or namespace or even just object that I fill with the desired modules.
But I keep getting syntax errors.

Currently my `foo/__init__.py` looks like this

```
import foo.subA.bar
import foo.subB.bar
import foo.subC.bar

class bar:
    def __init__(self):
        self.subA = foo.subA.bar
        self.subB = foo.subB.bar
        self.subC = foo.subC.bar
```

Which lets me import `foo` and `foo.bar` but trying to access
`foo.bar.subA` gives me

```
AttributeError: type object 'bar' has no attribute 'subA'
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing here, so I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work conveniently enough by introducing packages that take care of the aliasing, like this:

```
foo
| __init__.py
+ subA
| | __init__.py
| | bar.py
| ` baz.py
+ subB
| | __init__.py
| | bar.py
| ` baz.py
+ subC
| | __init__.py
| | bar.py
| ` baz.py
| bar.py
` baz.py
```

`bar.py` looks like this:

```py
import foo.subA.bar as subA
import foo.subB.bar as subB
import foo.subC.bar as subC
```

This allows me to `import foo.bar` and get `foo.bar.subA` which points to `foo/subA/bar.py`.

This isn't quite what I had in mind, since it requires me to maintain a list of aliases in `bar.py`, which I could do without, but it'll do.